# Having problem with Telegram Java bot deployment

Tags: java, heroku, deployment, telegram-bot

My bot works fine in IntellIJ IDE but when I deployed to Heroku it didn't work. I think the problem is with manifest. I have never deployed something so I didn't understand manifest or pom.xml. Please help me.

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>PhotoBot</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Main class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
        try{
            botsApi.registerBot(new PhotoBot());
        }catch (TelegramApiException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
```

[Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNlBJ.png)

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn02u.png)

[Pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDPVd.png)

Comment: Don't add code screenshot, copy code in the post. We can't edit the code in the screenshot.

Comment: ok lemme edit then

Comment: Please help guys